# How to scale an image in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

How to implement an image zooming by means of gestures? An `<Image />` has property `resizeMethod='scale'`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't zoom on images with a single code in both iOS and Android.
You can use `PhotoViewAndroid` native component and provide `onPhotoViewerScale` native prop for it or wrap an Image inside a `ScrollView` which it's contents are zoomable for iOS. 
I recommend using   [this component](https://github.com/alwx/react-native-photo-view).